# Python custom stdout filter

Tags: python, stdout

I was wondering if it is possible to filter the stdout of a `python` script. It calls another script (`ksh`) with subprocess [*]1 and it writes a message to console every time it does some operation. I want to surpress that message, that starts always with the substring `foo`.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT [*]1 `stdout` it is redirected to `subprocess.PIPE`

EDIT The code of the method and a disclaimer: I know that `shell=True` is highly discouraged but I couldn't make it work otherwise. This method calls a `ksh` custom shell that calls another command called `nexec`

```
def runNexec(self, command='pwd'):
    args=['nsh', '-c', 'nexec ' + self.name +' '+ command,'shell=True']

    p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (out, err) = (p.communicate())

    status = p.poll()

    if status != 0:
        return (1,log.log_error(err))
    else:
        return (0,out.splitlines())
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that runs the other script? You can control `subprocess.Popen()` to redirect the `stdout` and filter that, yes, but you need to show us your code.

Comment: `stdout` it is redirected to `subprocess.PIPE`

Comment: Then *show us the code*.

Comment: You did not set `shell=True` here, you added that to the argument list. I'm surprised that works *at all*. You are running the command `nsh` with three arguments, `-c`, `nexec <name> <command>` and `shell=True`. You can leave off that last element altogether, because it is already working without `shell=True`.

Comment: And what problems are you having here filtering `out` or `err` here? You now have two strings in Python, why can't you alter these?

Comment: is `p.communicate()` the actual command that writes the message that I want to remove from `stdout`.

Comment: `p.communicate()` waits for the subprocess to complete, while collecting everything that process writes to their stdout and stderr handles (which you redirected). That all ends up in the `out` and err` variables you now collected, you can do anything you want with those.

Comment: Yes, I know, but along with `out` and `err` there is a message that gets printed. My guess is that what I should edit is `PIPE` because is where `stdout` is redirected.. but I don't know how

Comment: No, I think you probably misunderstood something your Python code does. Try removing the call to `log.log_error()` for example.

Comment: Another possibility is that `nexec` is at fault here. It could conceivably bypass the pipe.

Comment: Thanks for all your time and effort. `log.log_error(message)` is a custom `print` command. that prints `[ERROR]+message`. If `nexec` or even `nsh -c` does bypass the pipe, how I may workaround the bypass?

Comment: `nsh` has it's stdout and stderr redirected. You'll have to look at the documentation for `nsh` and `nexec` to see what options they offer to control `stdout` and `stderr` redirection, that's well outside of Python's control.